# distinct keyword not working as expected in Azure cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to fetch a column value by applying distinct keyword on it, but when I execute the code sdk throw's

> Request rate is large. More Request Units may be needed, so no changes were made. Please retry this request later.

and when I execute the query in browser DB explorer I am getting the same counts thought I should be getting the less count as compared to without distinct.

```
 select value count(1) from (
  SELECT distinct c.fname from c where c.partition_key='employee'
 )
```

returns 17001, although it should return only 256 as it has only 356 distinct fname

```
 SELECT value count(1) from c where c.partition_key='employee'
```

returns the same count 17001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected result (yes, it's weird when I first encountered it )

check out this question, it should answer your question :

[Get distinct values in Cosmos DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925526/get-distinct-values-in-cosmos-db)

Also, I found this [blog post](https://spzsource.github.io/azure/2019/11/30/cosoms-db-distinct-count.html) explains this behavior thoroughly.